# How does this specific line of code work?

Tags: html, list, scala, sublist

I am a beginner to Scala and I recently went through http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/p09.scala and was trying to solve the problem.

Question: Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists. If a list contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.

```
scala> pack(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
```

Solution:

```
object P09 {
  def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
    if (ls.isEmpty) List(List())
    else {
      val (packed, next) = ls span { _ == ls.head }
      if (next == Nil) List(packed)
      else packed :: pack(next)
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: What actually does the line of code below do? How does it work?

```
val(packed, next) = l span {_ == l.head}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `items = xs ++ List(y) ++ zs` where all the elements in `xs` satisfy some predicate `pred` and `y` does *not* satisfy `pred`. In this case

```
items.span(pred) => (xs, List(y) ++ zs)
```

So what your line of code `l span {_ == l.head}` is doing is extracting all the equal elements from the front of the list into the first list `packed` and all the other elements into the second list `next`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, It was simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as we can see from the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) ...

```
def span(p: (A) => Boolean): (List[A], List[A])
```

... `span()` splits the `ls` list into 2 lists. The 1st list, `packed`, consists of all the initial elements that meet the predicate condition, `== ls.head`. The 2nd list, `next`, is the rest of the `ls` list that didn't make it into the 1st group, i.e. the 1st element that didn't meet the predicate condition and everything after that.

Here's a more concise expression of the same algorithm.

```
def pack[A](ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] = List.unfold(ls){  //<--Scala 2.13
  case Nil => None
  case lst => Some(lst.span(_ == lst.head))
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this your answer is quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The first span method just creates two collections, one which satisfies the condition and second which does not.

```
val(packed, next) = l span {_ == l.head}
```

Here `_` is syntactic sugar of Scala. It is same as `l.span(e => e == l.head)`. 
As Scala is very concise it provides syntactic sugars. You don't need to use the name of variables like e. span method receives values from a list and applies the filter to it. It filters all elements of a list in one collection which is equal to the value of the first element of the list.

I hope, it will help.

Comment: @Som Rai Your welcome. A good way of saying thanks is to accept the answer. :D